# Validation message contain '{PropertyName}' instead of name of property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation, fluentvalidation

I use fluent validation with client side unobtrusive validation.

```
 <fieldset class="edit-root-form">
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Login, UserRes.Login)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Login)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login)
    </p>         
</fieldset>
```

Fluent validation rule:

```
 this.RuleFor(x => x.Login).NotNull().EmailAddress()
```

And I got error message like this: '**{PropertyName}**' must not be empty.

Genered html:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="&amp;#39;{PropertyName}&amp;#39; is not a valid
email address."  data-val-required="&amp;#39;{PropertyName}&amp;#39; must not be
 empty." id="Login" name="Login" type="text" value="" class="input-validation-error">
```

Why MVC don`t replace **PropertyName**  real field name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me. I am using the latest FluentValidation version (2.0.0.0) and ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM.

Model and validator:

```
[Validator(typeof(MyViewModelValidator))]
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyViewModel>
{
    public MyViewModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Login).NotNull().EmailAddress();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model AppName.Models.MyViewModel
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Login, "Login")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Login)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

`Application_Start` in `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(new AttributedValidatorFactory()));
}
```

Two cases:

1. Leave the textbox empty: `'Login' must not be empty.` validation error message is shown.
2. Type an invalid email: `'Login' is not a valid email address.` validation error message is shown.

And finally here's the generated HTML for the textbox:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="&amp;#39;Login&amp;#39; is not a valid email address." data-val-regex-pattern="^(?:[\w\!\#\$\%\&amp;\&#39;\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#\$\%\&amp;\&#39;\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+@(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-](?!\.)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-](?!$)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]?)|(?:\[(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\]))$" data-val-required="&amp;#39;Login&amp;#39; must not be empty." id="Login" name="Login" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: I have created the project, using your example. And I still see {PropertyName} instead of real field name. I am using the same FluentValidation version (2.0.0.0) as you and ASP.NET MVC 3 version 3.0.11209.0

Comment: @Ivan, it seems that you are not using the RTM version. My `System.Web.Mvc` assembly has the version `3.0.20105.0` which is the RTM.

Comment: @Ivan, yes but did you uninstall any previous versions? Also make sure that your application points to the correct assembly.

Comment: I updated MVC to 3.0.20105. But error steel appears. Could you please look to my example: http://rapidshare.com/files/445598384/TestValidation.zip

Comment: @Darlin Dimitriv. Yes I did. I uninstalled old version and after that I installed new one. Now i`ll check it. Thank you for help.

Comment: @Ivan, yes indeed. It looks like the problem comes from the version of FluentValidation. My file is 80384bytes while your is 79360bytes, so not the same version. When I replaced FluentValidation.dll and FluentValidation.Mvc.dll with mine it worked fine. I've downloaded mine directly from the site: Thu Jan 13 2011 at 9:00 AM

Comment: It`s solutions! Thank you very much!